# Is it okey using WebSocket to get JSON on Android?

Tags: android, json, rest, http, websocket

I am developing client application on Android, which uses REST API to get JSON.
App sends a lot of requests to different URLs. This way is somehow slow - takes 30~60 seconds. [This article](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-01-05-websockets-vs-rest-api-understanding-the-difference/) says that `WebSocket` works faster. Now I am wondering  whether I can use `WebSocket`s for this purpose. So I have several questions about this:

1. Is it a good practice to use `WebSocket` to get JSON data from server?
   If not, what can be better(faster/more secure) than regular HTTP?
2. Can I send request to regular HTTP REST API using `WebSocket`?(this question may seem strange, but I really do not know)? Or guys on
   backend should change/modify something to make this enable?
3. What can be disadvantage(eg. battery drain) for using `WebSocket`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use WebSocket to get JSON data from a server.  However both the client and server must "talk" WebSocket.  If the server only understands REST calls, you will not be able to directly connect with WS from a browser to that REST server.
2. No, you cannot use WebSocket to directly connect to an HTTP REST API.  Your browser must use the same protocol as the server.  That's why protocols were invented. right?  :)
3. WebSocket is a persistent connection between a client and a server.  Its like a TCP socket connection in that way.  HTTP is fundamentally not persistent (although there are tricks to keep the connection for a long time).  An HTTP client usually calls an HTTP server, gets the data, returns and then the connection is terminated.  There are advantages and disadvantages to both (like anything else).  A WebSocket connection by itself will not drain your smartphone battery quickly.  If you are constantly sending data over that WebSocket that has to be rendered by the GPU on your screen, then your battery will drain.  An HTTP connection by itself will not drain your smartphone battery either.  But if your phone is polling some REST server and is in a low bandwidth area, your battery will drain from constantly going from low-power mode to high-power mode.  So its not the connection that is affecting the battery; its what's happening with that connection that affects the battery.

Comment: Thank you for your concise answer. This answer clarified me a lot of things about HTTP and WebSockets :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You still send HTTP requests. It is a good practice if you have a bunch of them that you want to send in a burst or want to have two-way interaction with the server. You simply avoid rebuilding a fresh Session everytime and multiple handshake protocols. If you want to visit a webpage with lots of resources (e.g. images) it is a good idea. Also the server can send request to you without being polled.
2. WebSockets need to be enabled on the server side (they are by default), but to keep the connection alive the webserver stores some references which need to be managed. So you allocate resources even if there is no messaging. When you have lots of clients, it can become challenging to handle the resource allocations.
3. Battery drain is not an issue since you are not sending lots of data, but for you as a developer you need to add extra logic to handle the cases when the network or wifi are no longer available. This is when the Websocket is terminated and you need to reconnect with the server.

As a personal comment: Use it if you need server to interact with you (if something happens e.g. a new message has arrived for you at the server, the server can use the websocket to let you know) or if you are expecting lots of requests being send to the server in a short time from your client.

Hope it helps! I am not an expert.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I appreciate your help :)